# How can I keep an API key secure from malicious attackers decompiling my app as well as detect malicious uses?

Tags: android, firebase, security, token, secret-key

I am currently developing an android application that uses an API secret and access tokens to access data over TLS.

Instead of storing the secret locally on the app in plaintext I am considering sending it over TLS from something like Firebase. I would send it encrypted and have a method of decryption that is fairly obfuscated. Then the API secret would be used to make requests to the API.

Are there considerations that should be made to protect the keys? My concern is that a malicious entity could decompile the app and insert their own code to find out our method of hiding the API key.

I'm not sure how someone could figure out the key now. I assume they'd decompile the code and redirect the API secret after it's been decrypted.

Eventually, no matter what, I understand that it could be hacked and someone could discover the API secret. How do I then detect that someone has the API secret? They can't hurt other users unless they have their access tokens, which is a different matter, but are there any well-known ways of detecting attacks? The only effect a malicious entity could have is sending many requests to the API servers pretending to be us which would increase our billing, but this should still be protected against. I could rotate my secret but if they already have a method of finding it, then this doesn't do much for me.

To summarize:
What is considered best practice? Should the API secret stay in our servers where we'd make requests from Firebase Functions? How does one detect an attack, or does this depend from API to API? If an attack is detected do I have to force users to update to a new version to make requests and hide the data in a new way in the new version?

I've put a lot of thought into this, but I still have questions I haven't found answers to myself or online. Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: you can't keep an API key secure unless you force users to log in explicitly each time. But even then, the user has the session key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing an API key in an app is problematic. You can obfuscate it or hide it in a computation, but if the secret is valuable enough, someone will extract it.

You are on a good track thinking about sending your key from a server. That keeps the key out of the app package itself. You must protect that communication, so TLS is a must, and you should go further and [pin the connection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.

Rather than sending the key itself, I would send a time-limited token signed by your API key. You'll need to send different tokens over time, but the API key is never directly exposed on the app, and you can change the signing key without requiring an app field upgrade. If a token is stolen, at least it is only valid for a limited period of time.

You still need to make sure you don't send tokens to a tampered app or even a bot who has reverse engineered your protocol. You need to authenticate the installed app package/code as well as check for a safe run time environment (not running in a debugger, no frameworks like frida or xposed, etc.). You could add tamper-detection to your app, but since you're already sending tokens to your app, I think it is a better approach to set up a challenge-response protocol which will cryptographically attest the app. That way you and not the app makes the actual authenticity decision.

For additional background on user and app authenticity, check out a 3 part blog post, starting with [Mobile API Security Techniques](https://hackernoon.com/mobile-api-security-techniques-682a5da4fe10), or if you prefer video, check out [A Tour of Mobile API Underprotection](https://hackernoon.com/a-tour-of-api-underprotection-2ad86fc5ce48). You can also look at [approov.io](https://approov.io) for a commercial implementation of challenge-response attestation and JWT tokens.

Comment: Thank you. This has been extremely helpful. I was hoping you might be able to clarify something regarding the time-limited token. If the client's app needs the API key to access the third parties API, and all they have is a signed key, how would that allow them to access the API? Also, do you have any resources regarding checking the runtime environment? Thank you for sharing your knowledge.